# The right way to load Angular 2 modules in components

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm using angular-cli starter kit and I have a question about using for example the "@angular/router" module.

In my `app.component.ts` I've imported the `@angular/router` module and used this in my `app.component.html` file and everything worked. When I wanted to create some other components like `view-header.component.ts` and `view-navbar.component.ts` and I wanted to do a `[routerLink]` there, I had to add the `@angular/router` module again. Clearly it's not the way how to use it, which leading to ask my question - How do I suppose to do this?.

And of course I've got an error because I didn't include in those components the required tag `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` Which implies it's really not the way how I should do it.

**Update 1**

Eventually I want to have a code like this:

app.component.html:

```
<view-header></view-header>
<view-navbar></view-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

(Just like ng-include in angular 1 which is now disabled in angular 2).

Answer (score 0):

Angular propose this solution in his website :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated'; 

import { viewNavbarComponent } from './view-navbar.component';
import { viewHeaderComponent } from './view-header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['ViewNavBar']">View navbar</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['ViewHeader']">View </a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/viewNavBar',
    name: 'ViewNavBar',
    component: viewNavbarComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '/viewHeader',
    name: 'ViewHeader',
    component: viewHeaderComponent
  }
])
export class AppComponent {

}
```

But take care, the current router is deprecated, maybe the method will change again...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not what I was looking for. What I wanted to do, is to split the HTML of my App to `header`, `navbar`, <router-outlet>, `footer`.  I want them as html templates, not as separate links.

Comment: So you want a template for your myAppComponent like : "<view-nav-bar></view-nav-bar><view-header></view-header><footer></footer>" if i understand correctly ?

Comment: yes, and I want to use in both of them the [routerLink] directive.

Answer (score 0):

Define the header and nav as directives and use them. and use route config to configure your routes.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated'; 

import { viewNavbarComponent } from './view-navbar.component';
import { viewHeaderComponent } from './view-header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <view-header></view-header>
    <view-navbar></view-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,VIEW_HEADER,VIEW_NAVBAR ],
  providers: [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/someView',
    name: 'SomeView',
    component: SomeViewComponent,
  }
])
export class AppComponent {

}
```